# Why XDocument.Load(url) throws exception?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, windows-phone-7, url-parsing

I am new to C# and I am trying to read xml from URL.
xml looks like this

```
<posts>
   <post>
      <title>title1</title>
      <des>des1</des>
   </post>
   <post>
      <title>title2</title>
      <des>des2</des>
   </post>
 .....
</posts>
```

And this is what I am using to parse it.

```
 String uri = "url";
 XDocument books = XDocument.Load(uri);
```

When the debug hits `XDocument` line it throws an exception and skips it.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: try with String uri = "url.xml"; Please let me know if this is helpful

Comment: What exception ??? please post details and stack trace of the exception with your question

Answer (score 0):

I think URI for your XML is lacking the extension of the file which is causing the problem. Please try using:

```
String uri = PATH + "url.xml"; 
XDocument books = new XDocument();
books.Load(uri);
```

To parse XML obtained from URL u can use:

```
string strURL = "http://<some-server>/<some-uri-path>";
string xmlStr;

WebClient wc = new WebClient();
xmlStr = wc.DownloadString(strURL);

XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlStr);
```

Comment: I am using php to create the xml so the url looks something like this

http://google.com?search=test

Comment: I have added modified code above. can u please check whether it suits your requirement

Comment: so I get this "System.Net.Webclient: type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to System.Idisposable. 
and System.Net.Webclient doestn't contain definition for DownloadString

Comment: after removing using block it should give the error of IDisposable. still I tried at my end. it does not give any error and it also has DownloadString method.

Comment: which namespaces are you using?

Comment: I am using System.Net.WebClient with .NET Framework 4.0 with Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: may be it's different for windows phone 
i am using visual studio 2012